# Express API Versioning with query params

Tags: node.js, api, express, api-design

I'm a NodeJS beginner and I'm developing an API backend using Express.

I have read many articles about how to do API versioning with Express but none of them explains how to use the query params approach.

I like doing API versioning like:

`example.org/users?version=1.0`

`example.org/users?version=1.1`

`example.org/users?version=1.2`

Etc. How can properly handle and structure my API code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that (this is just an example, you can play arround with it in many ways)

index.js:

```
var express= require('express')
, app = express()
, usersHandlers = require('./handlers/users');

app.use("/users",usersHandler);

function usersHandler(req,res){
    var version = req.query.version;
    console.log("This code is relevent for all versions");
    usersHandlers[version](req,res);
}

app.listen(8000,function(){
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/');
});
```

users.js:

```
module.exports = {
    '1.0' : function(req,res){
        res.send("This is the response for version 1.0");
    },
    '2.0' : function(req,res){
        res.send("This is the response for version 2.0");
    }
}
```